# Short story where science fiction saved the world

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This very short story was either in Asimov's or Analog. It was written like a mini history lesson. They replaced all books in schools with science fiction and all the kids grew up to be creative problem solvers and all the world's issues were resolved. Anyone know the title or author.

Comment: About when was it published?

Comment: Definitely not the answer because it's about as far from "short story" as you can get but Footfall by Niven and Pournelle features a group of sci-fi writers gathered together by the government to give advice on an alien invasion. Seems like sci-fi writers like their "saving the world" fantasies 

Comment: You might be able to find your story in this bibliography: https://data.nesfa.org/Recursion/

Comment: I read a story from Analog in that period in which science fiction is rediscovered in a future in which the solar system had been colonized but progress stopped there - and the rediscovery of SF leads to revival of a spirit of exploration.  Might that be the same one (if that sounds familiar, I'll look around for that story).